# View is not updating after adding element to MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, redux

[SOLVED]
I'm trying to make a small application with Redux/React/Mongo/Typescript and faced a problem, that when I'm adding element to database, I can see new added row in a table but without values in it. But after refreshing the page, values are there.
I think that this is because the array with records immediately refreshes, while new element is not in database yet. I used await/async but it didn't solve this problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Action.ts

```
export const getAllTeams: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<Promise<any>, 
    ITeam[],                 
    null,                       
    ITeamGetAllAction          
    >> = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/teams/')
            .then(res => {
                    dispatch({
                        teams: res.data,
                        type: TeamActionsTypes.GET_ALL,
                    })
                }
            );
    };
};
export const addTeam: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<Promise<any>,
    ITeamAddTeamAction,
    ITeam,
    ITeamAddTeamAction         
    >> = (team: ITeam) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/teams/add', team)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: TeamActionsTypes.ADD_TEAM,
                    result: res,
                });
            })
    };
};
```

Reducer.ts:

```
export const teamReducer: Reducer<ITeamState, TeamActions> = (
    state = initialTeamState,
    action,
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TeamActionsTypes.GET_ALL: {
            return {
                ...state,
                teams: action.teams,
            };
        }
        case TeamActionsTypes.ADD_TEAM: {
            return{
                ...state,
                teams: [action.result,...state.teams]
            }
        }
        case TeamActionsTypes.GET_ONE: {
            return{
                ...state,
            }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Component.tsx

```
interface RatingTableProps {
    getTeams: () => Promise<TeamActionsTypes.GET_ALL>;
    teams: ITeam[];
}

const RatingTable: React.FC<RatingTableProps> = ({
    getTeams,
    teams
}) => {
    useEffect(()=>{
        getTeams();
    },[]);

    return (
        <table className="striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th className="right-align">Clicks</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {teams && teams.map(team => {
                return <>
                    <tr key={team.name}>
                        <td>{team.name}</td>
                        <td className="right-align">{team.count}</td>
                    </tr>
                </>
            })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = (store: IAppState) => {
    return {
        teams: store.teamState.teams,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, AnyAction>) => {
    return {
        getTeams: () => dispatch(getAllTeams()),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RatingTable);
```

ComponentAdd.tsx

```
interface RatingFormProps{
    addTeam: (team: ITeam) => Promise<TeamActionsTypes.ADD_TEAM>;
}

const RatingForm: React.FC<RatingFormProps> = ({
    addTeam
})=> {
    const [teamName, setTeamName] = useState<string>('');

    const changeHandle = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setTeamName(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        addTeam({
            name: teamName,
            count: 0,
        });
        setTeamName('')
    };

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="inputField col s6">
                    <label htmlFor="teamName" className="active">
                        Name your team:
                    </label>
                    <input
                        onChange={changeHandle}
                        value={teamName}
                        type="text"
                        id="teamName"
                        placeholder="Best team name ever"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col s6">
                    <button className="btn-large waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )

};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, AnyAction>) => {
    return {
        addTeam: (team: ITeam) => dispatch(addTeam(team)),
    };
};

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(RatingForm);
```

teams.js(Routes)

```
router.route('/').get(async (req, res) => {
    await Team.find()
        .then(teams => res.json(teams))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post(async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const count = 0;
    const newTeam = new Team({name, count,});
    await newTeam.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Team added to database!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));

});
```

How it looks in UI:
[before adding new element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcAZy.png)
[after adding new element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z1rA.png)

If you need any additional information or code, please let me know. Thank you!

UPDATE 1:
Thank to the comment, of course one big error is to return actual object after posting, not a string(Shame on me)

```
router.route('/add').post(async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const count = 0;
    const newTeam = new Team({name, count,});
    await newTeam.save()
        .then((team) => res.json(team))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));

});
```

UPDATE 2:
OMG this was such a stupid error
The previous update solved an issue, but after I've recieved undefiened value from dipatch and this was because I was returning Promis, but not value.

```
export const addTeam: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<Promise<any>,
    ITeamAddTeamAction,
    ITeam,
    ITeamAddTeamAction         
    >> = (team: ITeam) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/teams/add', team)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: TeamActionsTypes.ADD_TEAM,
                    result: res.data, //<- Instead of just res
                });
            })
    };
};
```

Thanks to everyone, who spent some time on it, stupid errors as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the updated `team` from your back-end API. You can modify your API like this.

```js
router.route('/add').post(async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const count = 0;
    const newTeam = new Team({name, count,});
    await newTeam.save()
        .then(team => res.json(team))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));

});
```

Drop a comment if the problem still persists.

Comment: Yes, I've also found this problem, thank you very much, but It's still not showing in View, just a blank row

Comment: I will mark it as right answer, bacause it did solve the problem, thank you again!

Comment: You should try to add a lifecycle method like `componentWillReceiveProps` to change the props you recieve from the redux store.